# Create a column grouped by using similar values in another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to SQL/T-SQL and it would be great if anyone could help me solve this problem.

So I have a column RID:

```
RID 
111
111
111
222
222
222
333
333
333
```

Now I have to make use of t-sql ROW_NUMBER with BY GROUP or BY_PARTITION to make the following result:

```
RID  |  No
111 |  1
111 |  1
111 |  1
222 |  2
222 |  2
222 |  2
333 |  3
333 |  3
333 |  3
```

Thank you very much. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DENSE_RANK` Function will allow you to rank each row based on the value in `RID`.
See the mockup below:

```
DECLARE @TestTable table (RID INT)
INSERT INTO @TestTable
SELECT 111 UNION ALL
SELECT 111 UNION ALL
SELECT 111 UNION ALL
SELECT 222 UNION ALL
SELECT 222 UNION ALL
SELECT 222 UNION ALL
SELECT 333 UNION ALL
SELECT 333 UNION ALL
SELECT 333 UNION ALL
SELECT 333 



SELECT 
    RID, 
    [No]=DENSE_RANK() over (order by RID) 
FROM
    @TestTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select rid, dense_rank() over (order by rid) as num
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have use to dense_rank

```
select * ,dense_rank over (order by rid ) as No from t
```